# How can I use Cocoa beans in Minecraft Forge custom crafting recipes?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I'm creating a Minecraft mod with Forge, and I need to create a custom crafting recipe that uses cocoa beans. However, when I try to create the recipe, it does not work (as in, I cannot craft items with the specified pattern).

When `src/main/resources/assets/mymod/recipes/myrecipe.json` looks like this, it works fine:

```
{
    "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",

    "pattern": [
        " X ",
        " X ",
        " X "
    ],

    "key": {
        "X": {
            "item": "minecraft:iron_ingot"
        }
    },

    "result": {
        "item": "minecraft:gold_ingot",
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

but when it looks like this, I can't craft items with the recipe:

```
{
    "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",

    "pattern": [
        " X ",
        " X ",
        " X "
    ],

    "key": {
        "X": {
            "item": "minecraft:cocoa_beans"
        }
    },

    "result": {
        "item": "minecraft:gold_ingot",
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

According to https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Cocoa_Beans#ID, the name ID for cocoa beans is `minecraft:cocoa_beans`, which is exactly what I entered. However, the crafting recipe does not seem to be loaded into the game.

Why isn't the second crafting recipe working and how can I fix it?

I'm using Forge version 1.12.2-14.23.5.2768 and Eclipse version 2018-09 (4.9.0), and I'm running Minecraft directly from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Coco beans are brown dye.

[Dye](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Dye) has metadata values that determine which specific item it is (until 1.13 and The Flattening). The data value you're looking for in this case, is 3.

```
"key": {
    "X": {
        "item": "minecraft:dye",
        "data": 3
    }
},
```